La nuance entre vexer, blesser, froisser
Bonjour tout le monde,
J'aimerais bien mieux comprendre la nuance entre les trois mots dans le titre. Pour moi ils sont tous quasiment pareils, alors que j'imagine qu'il doit y avoir quand même une différence entre eux.
Pouvez-vous me donner des exemples quand il y en a un qui convient mieux que les autres ?
J'ai l'impression que « froisser » est un peu familier, que « blesser » est un peu fort, et que « vexer » insinue un peu de colère en plus du fait d'être blessé. Je me demande si je me trompe.
Merci.

À mon avis froisser n'est pas plus familier que les deux autres, je pense que c'est plutôt une question d'intensité qui différencie ces trois mots (froisser étant en bas de l'échelle). De plus je ne suis pas sure qu'il y ait entière synonymie entre vexer et les deux autres, je trouve que dans vexer il y a forcément une atteinte à l'amour propre que je ne vois pas dans tous les cas dans blesser et froisser, mais peut-être y a t-il dans ce dernier point une certaine subjectivité de ma part.

Merci @None - s'il s'avère que c'est le consensus, vous pouvez convertir votre commentaire en réponse et je l'accepterai.

par ordre croissant, je dirais froisser, vexer, blesser.

Dans le cas où ces trois verbes sont employés pour décrire une atteinte à notre amour propre ce sont des quasi synonymes mais j'y vois des degrés dans l'impact, toujours négatif, produit sur celui qui le reçoit.
Prenons l'exemple de la situation où je n'ai pas été invité à la fête organisée par des amis :

J'ai été (profondément) blessé de ne pas être invité à leur fête.

Blesser évoque l'image d'une atteinte physique, tel un membre cassé, une blessure qui saigne. C'est très douloureux.

J'ai été (profondément) vexé de ne pas être invité à leur fête.

Vexer n'évoque pas l'image d'une atteinte physique, ce qui peut suggérer une douleur moins intense.

J'ai été froissé de ne pas être invité à leur fête.

Froisser évoque une atteinte morale moindre. Et j'hésiterais à modifier le verbe froisser avec l'adverbe profondément. Pour  moduler l'intensité j'emploierais de préférence blesser ou vexer.
Par ailleurs l'emploi de froisser est me semble-t-il moins courant dans ce contexte, ce qui a pour conséquence de le rendre plus littéraire. En tous les cas il n'est pas du tout familier.
Froisser, et blesser (mais ce dernier dans une moindre mesure, c'est certainement moins courant) peuvent être employés pour une blessure morale qui n'est pas une atteinte à l'amour propre. Dans ce cas ils sont quasi synonymes de choquer et non de vexer.

Les discours de certains hommes politiques me froissent.

Ce n'est pas mon amour propre qui est atteint dans ce cas, mais la représentation que je me fais d'un certain idéal/de certaines normes sociales. L'emploi d'un adverbe d'intensité peut ici être employé sans problème.

Grammaticalement, ces trois verbes sont parfaitement interchangeables. Stylistiquement, ils sont du même registre. Sémantiquement, ils sont cousins: tous décrivent une atteinte dont l'amour-propre est victime; ils diffèrent par l'image qu'ils amènent à l'esprit du lecteur, par l'idée associée.

froisser suggère l'inconfort: l'atteinte est douloureuse, comme un muscle froissé;
blesser, les dégâts: l'atteinte produit un "saignement d'amour-propre", voire une mutilation;
vexer, la malveillance: l'atteinte est malicieuse et harcelante, elle cherche à tourmenter au-delà du supportable (latin vexare: torturer).


Très bien expliqué, merci beaucoup.
